# Программно изменить текущую строку в DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем. Такой вопрос.

Как программным способом изменить текущую строку в DataGridView? Не выделить, а сделать текущей! Тоесть в DataGridView отображении она будет выглядить как выделенная, и черный треугольничек будет строять на ней. 
Мне нужно изменять текущую строку на добавленную в DataGridView. Подписываюсь на событие и делаю так:

```
this.dataDataGridView.RowsAdded += (s, e) =>
{
    this.dataDataGridView.CurrentCell = this.dataDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().First(c => c.Visible);
};
```

Добавленная строка выделяется, но черный треугольничек остается там же, где и был. Как и его передвинуть?

Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: вы устанавливаете текущую ячейку, но не строку, посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635731/how-to-set-focus-on-a-particular-row-in-a-datagrid-gridview

Comment: свойство CurrentRow у DataGridView только для чтения. Приходится через текущую ячейку делать...да один фиг не получается. И по той ссылки, которую вы дали, результат также не нашли

Comment: Ну что, кто-нибудь знает?